# Create PDF in .Net

Tags: library, pdf, .net

I am looking for a library to create PDF in web form asp.net application.

My requirement is as follow:
I have to get the data from the database and build PDF, the data can either be a plain text or HTML content. So I am looking for a the library which can parse the HTML content as well and display it on PDF, build tables, formatting the PDF etc.

I have researched online and found itextsharp for .net which is popular and most powerful but looks like they have made it a paid licence when used for commercial purpose. So I am looking for some thing which is open source or else if it is less expensive librabry.

Answer (score 1):

I used [GemBox.Document](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/overview), it supports writing PDF files, importing both plain text and HTML content, creating and formatting tables, etc.

If interested here is how I used it:

1. Load input word document that has placeholders (merge fields) that should be filled out with data from my data source.
2. Retrieve data source from my database.
3. Executed [mail merging](http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/Document/help/html/Mail_Merge.htm).
4. Save output PDF document.

FYI this article (www.gemboxsoftware.com/support-center/kb/articles/41-how-to-insert-html-and-rtf-content-during-the-mail-merge-process) shows how you can customize mail merging so that you can import a HTML content.

Last it has both Free and Pro modes, but Free mode has some document size limitation.

Answer (score 0):

[Essential PDF](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) can be used to build PDFs. It supports binding to data or inserting content as needed.

The entire product is available for free with no limitations through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify.

Note: I work for Syncfusion